# Postgres что означает лог/что происходит/откуда такое может взяться/что пытается сделать?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker

На сервере на Ubuntu запускаю сервисы

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db_host:
    container_name: database
    image: postgres:16.1
    env_file:
      - "bot/data/.env"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "****"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
      - botnet
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgres/data
      - ./backups:/backups

  rediska:
    container_name: rediska
    image: "redis:5.0.1"
    restart: always
    command: redis-server
    networks:
      - botnet
    volumes:
      - rediska_v_sarafane:/etc/redis/data

  sar_bot:
    container_name: alche_sarbot
    build:
      context: .
    command: python main.py
    networks:
      - botnet
    env_file:
      - "bot/data/.env"
    volumes:
      - .:/sarbot
    depends_on:
      - db_host
      - rediska

volumes:
  pgdata:
  rediska_v_sarafane:

networks:
  botnet:
    driver:
      bridge
```

Докер-файл

```
FROM python:3.11.5-alpine3.18

RUN apk update && \
    apk add musl-dev libpq-dev gcc

WORKDIR /sarbot

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

при запуске сервиса `sar_bot`создаётся база данных и таблицы в ней через подключение к сервису `db_host`

Никаких действий больше не произвожу
Через пару минут простоя получаю вот такой лог

```
database   | 2024-02-11 05:41:38.803 UTC [59] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
database   | 2024-02-11 05:43:18.215 UTC [59] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 995 buffers (6.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=99.349 s, sync=0.047 s, total=99.412 s; sync files=379, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4715 kB, estimate=4715 kB; lsn=0/1985990, redo lsn=0/1985958
database   | bash: line 2: pkill: command not found
database   | bash: line 3: pkill: command not found
database   | bash: line 4: pkill: command not found
database   | chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/ld.so.preload
database   | chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /var/spool/cron
database   | chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/crontab
database   | bash: line 9: ufw: command not found
database   | bash: line 10: iptables: command not found
database   | bash: line 11: /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog: Read-only file system
database   | bash: line 12: /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied
database   | bash: line 166: curl: command not found
database   | bash: line 166: /usr/local/bin/curl: Permission denied
database   | chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/curl': No such file or directory
database   | bash: line 167: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory
database   | bash: line 168: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory
database   | chmod: cannot access '/tmp/curl': No such file or directory
database   | bash: line 171: /tmp/curl: No such file or directory
database   | main: line 236: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 237: pkill: command not found
...
database   | main: line 242: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 243: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 244: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 245: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 246: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 247: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 248: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 249: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 250: ps: command not found
..
database   | main: line 253: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 254: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 255: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 256: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 257: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 258: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 259: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 260: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 261: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 262: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 263: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 264: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 265: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 266: pkill: command not found
...
database   | main: line 291: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 292: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 293: ps: command not found
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.X11-unix/01: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/01: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.X11-unix/11: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/11: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.X11-unix/22: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/22: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.systemd.1: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.1: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.systemd.2: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.2: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.systemd.3: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.3: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.1: No such file or directory
database   | kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.2: No such file or directory
database   | kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.3: No such file or directory
database   | kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.pg_stat.0: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.pg_stat.0: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.pg_stat.1: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.pg_stat.1: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /var/lib/postgresql/data/./oka.pid: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /var/lib/postgresql/data/./oka.pid: No such file or directory
database   | main: line 315: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 316: pkill: command not found
...
database   | main: line 320: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 321: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 322: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 323: ps: command not found
..
database   | main: line 326: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 327: ps: command not found
database   | md5sum: /tmp/kinsing: No such file or directory
database   | /tmp/kinsing is not b3039abf2ad5202f4a9363b418002351, actual
database   | chmod: cannot access '/tmp/kinsing': No such file or directory
database   |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
database   |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 5828k  100 5828k    0     0  2611k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 2609k
database   | /tmp/kinsing is b3039abf2ad5202f4a9363b418002351
database   | md5sum: /tmp/libsystem.so: No such file or directory
database   | /tmp/libsystem.so is not ccef46c7edf9131ccffc47bd69eb743b, actual
database   | chmod: cannot access '/tmp/libsystem.so': No such file or directory
database   |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
database   |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 26800  100 26800    0     0   6052      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  6052
database   | /tmp/libsystem.so is ccef46c7edf9131ccffc47bd69eb743b
database   |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
database   |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 26800  100 26800    0     0   6200      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  6200
database   | /tmp/libsystem.so is ccef46c7edf9131ccffc47bd69eb743b
database   | main: line 358: /etc/ld.so.preload: Permission denied
database   | main: line 362: crontab: command not found
database   | main: line 362: crontab: command not found
...
database   | main: line 423: crontab: command not found
database   | main: line 423: crontab: command not found
database   | bash: line 467: crontab: command not found
database   | bash: line 474: crontab: command not found
database   | 2024-02-11 05:43:52.148 UTC [969] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
database   | 2024-02-11 05:43:52.148 UTC [969] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
database   | 2024-02-11 05:43:52.148 UTC [969] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER postgres WITH NOSUPERUSER
database   | 2024-02-11 05:43:53.228 UTC [90] WARNING:  role "postgres" has not been granted membership in role "pg_execute_server_program" by role "postgres"
database   | bash: line 2: pkill: command not found
database   | bash: line 3: pkill: command not found
database   | bash: line 4: pkill: command not found
database   | chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/ld.so.preload
database   | chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /var/spool/cron
database   | chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/crontab
database   | bash: line 9: ufw: command not found
database   | bash: line 10: iptables: command not found
database   | bash: line 11: /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog: Read-only file system
database   | bash: line 12: /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied
database   | bash: line 166: curl: command not found
database   | bash: line 166: /usr/local/bin/curl: Permission denied
database   | chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/curl': No such file or directory
database   | bash: line 167: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory
database   | bash: line 168: /usr/local/bin/curl: No such file or directory
database   | 2024-02-11 05:44:15.226 UTC [1391] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
database   | 2024-02-11 05:44:15.553 UTC [1393] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
database   | chmod: cannot access '/tmp/curl': No such file or directory
database   | bash: line 171: /tmp/curl: No such file or directory
database   | main: line 236: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 237: pkill: command not found
...
database   | main: line 242: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 243: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 244: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 245: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 246: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 247: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 248: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 249: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 250: ps: command not found
...
database   | main: line 253: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 254: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 255: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 256: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 257: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 258: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 259: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 260: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 261: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 262: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 263: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 264: netstat: command not found
database   | main: line 265: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 266: pkill: command not found
...
database   | main: line 291: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 292: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 293: ps: command not found
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.X11-unix/01: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/01: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.X11-unix/11: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/11: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.X11-unix/22: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/22: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.systemd.1: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.1: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.systemd.2: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.2: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.systemd.3: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.3: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.1: No such file or directory
database   | kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.2: No such file or directory
database   | kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
database   | cat: /tmp/.systemd.3: No such file or directory
database   | kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.pg_stat.0: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.pg_stat.0: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /tmp/.pg_stat.1: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /tmp/.pg_stat.1: No such file or directory
database   | sed: can't read /var/lib/postgresql/data/./oka.pid: No such file or directory
database   | cat: /var/lib/postgresql/data/./oka.pid: No such file or directory
database   | main: line 315: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 316: pkill: command not found
...
database   | main: line 320: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 321: pkill: command not found
database   | main: line 322: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 323: ps: command not found
...
database   | main: line 326: ps: command not found
database   | main: line 327: ps: command not found
database   | /tmp/kinsing is b3039abf2ad5202f4a9363b418002351
database   | /tmp/libsystem.so is ccef46c7edf9131ccffc47bd69eb743b
database   | main: line 358: /etc/ld.so.preload: Permission denied
database   | main: line 362: crontab: command not found
database   | main: line 362: crontab: command not found
...
database   | main: line 423: crontab: command not found
database   | bash: line 467: crontab: command not found
database   | bash: line 474: crontab: command not found
database   | 2024-02-11 05:46:38.320 UTC [59] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
database   | 2024-02-11 05:46:42.775 UTC [59] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 45 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.427 s, sync=0.008 s, total=4.455 s; sync files=37, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=168 kB, estimate=4260 kB; lsn=0/19AF9E0, redo lsn=0/19AF9A8
```

Что это вообще может быть? Это так и должно быть? Откуда оно может взяться? И что вообще происходит? Если это надо чинить, то куда копать?

п.с. Доп вопрос. По какой-то причине база данных самоудаляется через несколько дней, хотя ничего не происходит, она простаивает, и раз в сутки делается бэкап командой `docker exec -it database ~/script_backup.sh`
Те же вопросы, откуда/зачем/куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что это вообще может быть?

Снаружи чей-то бот попробовал подсоединиться внешнему IP вашего виртуального сервера к порту TCP/5433. Поскольку файервол не настроен и разрешает любые подключения снаружи, а в `ports:` в `docker-compose.yml` у вас написано `5433:5432`, а не `127.0.0.1:5433:5432` (т. е. порт 5433 выставлен в интернет), это ему удалось, ведь на порту 5433 отвечает поднятый вами контейнер `db_host`. Поскольку вы не меняли имя суперпользователя PostgreSQL на какое-то другое через переменную `POSTGRES_USER` - подошло стандартное имя `postgres`. В `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` у вас видимо достаточно простой пароль, поскольку, если бы его не удалось подобрать, ничего этого бы не было. Но, судя по логу, пароль подобран. И чей-то бот теперь пользуется возможностью суперпользователя PostgreSQL на выполнение команд в ОС (в данном случае - в контейнере `db_host`).

> Это так и должно быть?

Так и должно быть, если бездумно выставлять порты докера в интернет и при этом не закрывать их файерволом на хостовой ОС. Вообще же об этом обычно думают и знают, закрыты ли у них порты файерволом на хостовой ОС (и закрывают, если не требуется давать сервисам на этих портах доступ снаружи), знают, нужно ли им пробрасывать контейнер в интернет (и если не нужно - ограничивают адресом localhost'а 127.0.0.1), и ставят достаточно сложный пароль.

> Откуда оно может взяться?

Бот из интернета подобрал пароль.

> Если это надо чинить, то куда копать?

Настройка iptables/nftables/firewalld/ufw/что-там-бывает-ещё (в зависимости от вашей ОС), корректное определение `ports:` в `docker-composer.yml`, более сложный пароль.

Comment: О! Спасибо большое! Очень-очень-очень спасибо за такой крутой развёрнутый ответ! 

Ubuntu 22.04 на сервере ОС) Теперь буду выяснять, как закрыть порты фаерволлом на хостовой ОС)